# PHPickerViewControllerDelegate load item using async await

Tags: ios, swift, phpickerviewcontroller

I can't find much documented regarding the PHPickerViewControllerDelegate didFinishPicking function using async await and I'm not sure I understand how to use the NSItemProvider. Here is my delegate code:

```
    func picker( _ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]){
    for result in results {
        Task {
            if result.itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(UTType.image.identifier) {
                do {
                    let url = try await result.itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.image.identifier) as! URL
                    print(url.description)
                    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                    let image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When used in the simulator the ItemProvider returns a URL but the data content of that URL is empty. How do I grab the image from the ItemProvider? Thanks

Comment: If you want the data then I would use `loadDataRepresentation` instead of `loadItem`.

Comment: loadDataRepresentation is not available with async/await which I would prefer. What exactly does loadItem return? I don't necessarily need data, just the image and (if possible) metadata.

Comment: It's a shame only `loadItem` comes in the `async` form. To me that's the least clear method since there's no way to know what it's going to return.